# How do you iteratre over a list performing some operation that turns a single element into multiple?

Tags: python

I have a csv file of data from a LiDAR sensor that looks like this, but with a bagillion more lines:

```
scan_0,scan_1,scan_2
timestamp_0,timestamp_1,timestamp_2
7900200,7900225,7900250
logTime_0,logTime_1,logTime_2
27:46.8,27:46.8,27:46.8
distance_0,distance_0,distance_0
132,141,139
136,141,155
139,141,155
138,143,155
138,143,142
139,143,136
138,143,136
```

This is data from a planar sensor. So Scan_0 is a list or "radial" coordinates for the specific scan at a time stamp.

My plan is to:

1. Read the CSV file into a list
2. Transpose the list
3. Turn each element of row into a xyz format like the example below.

   ```
   scan_0 -----> scan_0
   timestamp_0-> timestamp_0
   7900200-----> 7900200
   logTime_0---> logTime_0
   27:46.8-----> 27:46.8
   distance_0--> distance_0
   132---------> [132*cos(1),132*sin(1),7900200]
   136---------> [136*cos(2),136*sin(2),7900200]
   139---------> [139*cos(3),139*sin(3),7900200]
   138--------->          .          .
   138--------->          .          .
   139--------->          .          .
   138---------> [138*cos(7),139*sin(7),7900200]
   ```
4. Write the array of xyz coordinates to a new csv file with one coordinate per line'
5. eventually use a trajectory instead of timestamp for the z coordinate from another csv file.

I tell you all of this, so you have some context for my motivation.

here is what I have so far:

```
import csv 
import numpy
from numpy import genfromtxt
from numpy import vsplit
import math

with open('2016_09_16_14_29_09_953.csv',"r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ",")
    data = list(reader)
    row_count = len(data)
print row_count
with open("out.csv", "a") as f1:
    my_r = genfromtxt('2016_09_16_14_29_09_953.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=6, autostrip=True) #import data
    my_r = my_r.T #transpose
    for x in my_r:
        i=0
        while i < row_count/360:
            x = [x*math.cos(i), x*math.sin(i), i]
            i = i + row_count/360

    thedatawriter = csv.writer(f1) #setup writer
    for row in my_r: #write the data
        thedatawriter.writerow(row)
```

All this really does it ouput the transpose of the source file. It appears that I am having trouble turning the single entry in the list into a list itself. What am I doing wrong here? Any help, advice, and guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is that you are trying to assign new value to variable that does not reference to array.

So you have

```
for x in my_r:
    i=0
    while i < row_count/360:
        x = [x*math.cos(i), x*math.sin(i), i]
        i = i + row_count/360
```

You cannot do that, because x is not actual element of `my_r` list(changing `x` would not lead to changing element on `my_r`).

The simplest way is to create new array to store desired values.

```
my_r = genfromtxt('2016_09_16_14_29_09_953.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=6, autostrip=True) #import data
my_r = my_r.T #transpose
new_r = []
for x in my_r:
    i=0
    while i < row_count/360:
        new_r.append([x*math.cos(i), x*math.sin(i), i])
        i = i + row_count/360
thedatawriter = csv.writer(f1) #setup writer
for row in new_r: #write the data
    thedatawriter.writerow(row)
```